# Reconnect to Laravel Echo server after session disconnection

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I am attempting to write an web application with a persistent echo connection to a laravel-echo-server instance, which needs to detect disconnections and attempt to reconnect gracefully. The scenario I am attempting to overcome now is a user's machine has gone to sleep / reawoke and their session key has been invalidated (echo server requires an active session in our app). Detecting this situation from an HTTP perspective is solved - I setup a regular keepAlive, and if that keepAlive detects a 400-level error, it reconnects and updates the session auth_token.

When my Laravel session dies, I cannot tell that has happened from an echo perspective. The best I've found is I can attach to the 'disconnect' event, but that only gets triggered if the server-side laravel-echo-server process dies, rather than the session is invalid:

```
        this.echoConnection.connector.socket.on('connect', function() {
            logger.log('info', `Echo server running`);
        })
        this.echoConnection.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            logger.log('warn', `Echo server disconnected`);
        });
```

On the laravel-echo-server side, I can tell that the connection is dead - it will show this error:

```
⚠ [7:03:30 PM] - 5TwHN2qUys5VEFP5AAAG could not be authenticated to private.1
```

I cannot figure out how to catch this failure event programmatically from the client. Is there a way to capture it? Again, I can tell the session is dead eventually because I poll the server regularly via a http keepAlive function, but I would definitely also like to tell directly from the echo connection if possible, as it polls at a much higher natural rate.

As a second (more important) question, if I detect that my session has died, what should I do to recycle the echo connection (after I have logged in again via HTTP and gotten a new auth_token)? Is there anything specific I should call / etc? I've had some success calling disconnect() then setting up the connection again from scratch, but I do see errors such as:

```
websocket.js:201 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

Here is my current (naive) reconnection code, which is my initial connection code with an attempt to disconnect first stapled onto it:

```
    async attemptEchoReconnect() {

        if (this.echoConnection !== null) {
            this.echoConnection.disconnect();
            this.echoConnection = null;
        }

        const thisConnectionParams = this.props.connections[this.connectionName];
        const curThis = this;

        this.echoConnection = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            host: thisConnectionParams.echoHost,
            authEndpoint: 'api/broadcasting/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ` + thisConnectionParams.authToken
                }
            }
        });

        this.echoConnection.connector.socket.on('connect', function() {
            logger.log('info', `Echo server running`);
        })
        this.echoConnection.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            logger.log('warn', `Echo server disconnected`);
        });

        this.echoConnection.join('everywhere')
            .here(users => {
                logger.log('info', `Rejoined presence channel`);
            });

        this.echoConnection.private(`private.${this.props.id}`)
            .listen(...);

        setTimeout(() => { this.keepAlive() }, 120 * 1000);
    }
```

Any help would be so great - these APIs are not well documented to the end that I really want, and I am hoping I can get some stability with this connection rather than having to do something ugly like force restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs help with this problem, my above echo reconnection code seems to be pretty stable, along with a keepAlive function to determine the state of the HTTP connection. I am still a bit uncertain of the origin of the console errors I am seeing, but I suspect they have to do with connection loss during a sleep cycle, which is not something I am particularly worried about.

I'd still be interested in hearing other thoughts if anyone has any. I am somewhat inclined to believe long-term stability of an echo connection is possible, though it does appear you have to proactively monitor it with what tools you have available.